# Recover broken MySQL database after setting Windows back to an earlier date

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mysql, file-recovery

Yesterday after a driver update my Windows crashed and I got a BSOD right at startup so I didn't had a choice I set Windows back to the last working point but sadly my last working restore point is from few days ago and since than I was working on a lots of stuff and this restoration messed up two of my databases.

Now when I check the database I see every table in the schema view but when I click it of course it says table doesn't exist.

So I checked `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\mydb\` and there I saw that the `.MYD` and `.MYI` files are missing for those tables and only the `.frm` files are there.

Than I tried to run Recuva on the folder but it didn't found anything.

Is there any way to recover those lost tables or I have to start my work form the beginning?

Comment: Is there a restore point from the driver installation?

Comment: yes there is but when I tried to set Windows to that the restore process throw an error and it did not restore Windows so I chose the clostet date which was made by Avast before I updated it and that worked

Comment: I don't understand... so the problem was already solved? Maybe this helps: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/193282-system-restore-points-manually-extract-files-folders.html

Comment: No the problem isn't solved, because the restoration process damaged 2 database in MySQL which I was working on and I want to recover those MySQL tables which were lost.

Comment: Does my link help?

Comment: I was able to extract the files from the restore point but when I copy the files back to programdata and run a query on the database mysql chrashes instantly but I will figure out a way to resolve that. So in short YES that worked. If you put it in an answer I will check is as solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23395/discussion-between-davidbaumann-and-laci-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the files from your latest restore point using http://nicbedford.co.uk/software/systemrestoreexplorer/

Just copy them to your mysql folder (I would backup the old files before).

Here you can see, how to restore the data from a backup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680261/restore-mysql-database-folder-from-a-recovered-hard-disk

In fact, you should stop all mysql services before copying the files.

After restore, check all the tables.